# A non-recursive tree node removal method?

Tags: java, tree, nodes

How is the best way to go about writing a non-recursive node removal method?

I have this to start things off:

```
public deezNodes remove(int x) {
    if (this == nullnode ) return nullnode;

    if (x < this.iData) {
        this.left = this.left.remove(x);
    } else if (x > this.iData) {
        this.right = this.right.remove(x);
    } else if (this.left == nullnode) {
        return this.right;
    } else if (this.right == nullnode ) { 
        return this.left;
    } else { // Two children
        this.iData = (this.left).rmLarge(this).iData;
    }
    return this;
}
```

My kneejerk response would be replacing instances of recursion with further if/else clauses until the node is found. I'm wondering if there is a more elegant way.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: If you're removing the recursion, you need to use iteration instead. You need a loop somewhere.

Comment: A standard method of unwrapping a recursion is by using a stack or queue of nodes, initiate it with the start-node (the root) and iterate while the stack/queue is not empty, where each iteration adds the child node to the stack/queue. Choice of stack or queue will affect the search pattern (depth-first vs. breadth-first).